# Как правильно завершить многопоточный скрипт на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Пишу чат, есть серверная и клиентская часть, работает по TCP. Реализован с помощью многопоточности.

Возникла проблема, как правильно завершать работу таких скриптов? В данном случае, в `__init__` в потоке `MainThread`, вызывает функцию `send_message`, в потоке `Thread-1`.
`__init__` в цикле проверяет, если `kill_treads = False` то цикл работает. По `/stop`, я переключаю `kill_treads` в `True`, что вызывает остановку `MainThread`, и `Thread-1` становится `MainThread`. Я проверяю, если функция `send_message` находится в потоке `MainThread`, то кидаю выход.
Но, после ввода `/stop`, выход не происходит, приходится вводить ещё что-то что бы выключилось.
Как это можно исправить и правильно завершить многопоточный скрипт?

```
import socket
import threading
import sys


class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send_message(self):
        while True:

            if threading.currentThread().getName() == 'MainThread':
                # если  текущий поток главный, то выходим
                print('Exit')
                self.sock.close()   # закрываем соединение
                sys.exit(1)         # выходим из скрипта

            try:

                # print('Send message: ', end='')
                message = input()
                if message == '/stop':          # для выхода из программы
                    self.kill_treads = True     # выключает главный цикл

                else:
                    # печатаем сообщение
                    self.sock.send(bytes(message, 'utf-8'))

            except EOFError:
                print('[Something gona wrong. Connection lost]')
                self.kiil_treads = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.kill_treads = False
        # запускаем сервер, заставляя слушать локалхост
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 4242))
        print('Соединение активированно\n')
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_message)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        while not self.kill_treads:

            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(str(data, 'utf-8'))
            print(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    client.send_message()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в этом случае проще всего закрыть сокет:

```
 if message == '/stop':          # для выхода из программы
    self.kill_treads = True     # выключает главный цикл
    self.sock.close()           # закрывает сокет. В читающем потоке будет брошено исключение
```

Брошенное исключение, нужно поймать и обработать, чтобы програма не завершалась аварийно:

```
try:
   data = self.sock.recv(1024)
except Exception as e:
   break
```